# Printing dictionary with lists into file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I writing a script in python in which I am extracting some information from some files and passing it into another file.

I have 2 dictionaries that contains lists of elements of a class, and I want to write each element of the list into a .csv file.

When I try to write the data to the file it appears in a weird way. I want the data to appear in this way:

```
Sample_3 45526536 7010285 31195850 7320401 45500691 7186449 31021951 7292291  
Sample_1 48885783 7715654 33474067 7696062 48857972 7907873 33282945 7667154
```

but instead I have this result:

```
 Sample_3 ['45526536'] ['7010285'] ['31195850'] ['7320401'] ['45500691'] ['7186449'] ['31021951'] ['7292291']
 Sample_1 ['48885783'] ['7715654'] ['33474067'] ['7696062'] ['48857972'] ['7907873'] ['33282945']['7667154']
```

Does anyone know why is adding [´´] to the numbers? I try to make an really simple method to eliminate the [' '] but then I won't print anything in the file.

```
def correct_str(value):  
    new= str(value).strip("['")
    final= str(new).strip("']")
    return final
```

Here is the code here I am adding elements to the dictionary, the dictionary is a global variable called stat_dict_l_u, and the name is the key to the dictionary, in this case Sample_1 and Sample_2, and list values is a list that contains the numbers I got from a file. I believe that maybe my problem comes from the way I am adding the values to the dictionary.

```
def processNumbersLeft(name,list_values):

    list_reads=[]


    for value in list_values:
        print value.total_reads
        list_reads.append(value.total_reads)



    list_aligned_once=[]
    for value in list_values:

        n=re.split(" ",value.aligned_once)
                 list_aligned_once.append(n[0])


    list_failed=[]
    for value in list_values:

        n=re.split(" ",value.failed)
        list_failed.append(n[0])

    list_aligned_several=[]
    for value in list_values:

        n=re.split(" ",value.aligned_several)

        list_aligned_several.append(n[0])



    stat_elem=Statistics(list_reads,list_aligned_once,list_failed,list_aligned_several)

    stat_dict_l_u[name]=stat_elem
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are using to get the wrong results?

Comment: please, print `repr(d)` of your dictionaries.

Comment: When I use repr(d) i have this result: {'Sample_3': <__main__.Statistics instance at 0x2b5034122b48>, 'Sample_1': <__main__.Statistics instance at 0x2b503411fdd0>}

Comment: Solved it was in the code, the way I was adding the values to the dictionary. Solution: stat_elem=Statistics(list_reads[0],list_aligned_once[0],list_failed[0],list_aligned_several[0])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this case:

```
def to_file(d):
    return '\n'.join("%s %s" % (key, ' '.join(map(str, values))) for key, values in d.items())
```

Using:

```
>>> print to_file({'Sample_1': [1,2,3], 'Sample_2': [4,5,6]})
Sample_1 1 2 3
Sample_2 4 5 6
```

Note, if you need to a lot of work with csv-file, use helpful module [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). Example of using:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for key, values in d.items():
        spamwriter.writerow([key] + values)
```

This example does exactly what you need. For more information read [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Comment: So how did the OP end up with separate lists for each element? Either his data looks like `[['one'], ['two'], ['three'], ...]`, or he's using slicing instead of indexing (`lst[0:0]`, `list[1:1]`, etc).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, in any case, we are not mind readers, and can not accurately determine what exactly the problem without the code.

Comment: @defuz I tried your code it didn't help, it gives an error:     writer.writerow([key] + values)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "instance") to list.        Anyway I need to write elements from 2 dictionaries to my file

Comment: @Leo.peis, The problem is not in the code. `values` in your dict are some objects, not `list`. Should be: `d = {"Sample 1": [1, 2, 3], "Sapmle2": [4, 5, 6]}`. Print your `d` here.

Comment: great answer. just used this for a related problem. wish it had been easier to find, though

Answer (score 2):

When writing data to a file, it'll turn your objects into strings. The `['']` notation indicates your data is contained in lists.

You want to write `value[0]` instead of `value` for each entry.

To illustrate:

```
>>> value = ['foobar']
>>> value
['foobar']
>>> str(value)
"['foobar']"
>>> value[0]
'foobar'
```